# powershell javascript eval() or vbscript execute() alternative?

Tags: javascript, powershell, vbscript, eval

I've thought that the `$("some string")` will do it but it did not:

```
 $c="$a=5;$b=11+3;$a+$b"
 $($c)
```

- I've expected to see 19.

`Invoke-Expression`  ?

Answer (score 1):

First you should escape your $ character with a backquote ` :

```
$c = "`$a=5;`$b=11+3;`$a+`$b"
```

Then you can directly call the powershell command to execute your code :

```
PS C:\> powershell -command $c
19
```

Answer (score 1):

'=' and '+' are being treated as string rather than operators when you enclosed them inside double quotes. Try putting it in a scriptblock instead like:

```
PS C:\> $c={$a=5;$b=11+3;$a+$b}
PS C:\> & $c
19
```